# How do I get PowerShell script to delete users on other computers?

Tags: powershell, scripting, virtual-machine

I am testing a script locally to delete user accounts on a VM. This is the script:

```
#This script will do the following actions:
#1.- Get a computer list from a TXT file
#2.- Get a list of users from a TXT to be removed from the local users group
#3.- Do a ping to every computer on the list, if the computer is offline it will skip it and pass to the next one
#4.- If the computer answers the ping it will search into the local users group and if a user matches with a user from the user list it will be removed
#5.- Creates a log with all the transactions

# Log Time Variables
$Date = Get-Date -UFormat %b-%m-%Y
$Hour = (Get-Date).Hour
$Minutes = (Get-Date).Minute
$Log = "C:\Scripts\Remove-LocalAdmins Masive-" + $Date + "-" + $Hour + "-" + $Minutes + ".log"

#Creates a log file for this process
Start-Transcript -Path $Log  -Force 

#List of computers to be check
$ComputerNames = Get-Content "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\User Deletion Scripts\TestLocal.txt"

#Ping the computers on the list
foreach ($ComputerName in $ComputerNames) {

#If theres no ping answer pass to the next one
if ( -not(Test-Connection $ComputerName -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction Continue )) {
Write-Output "Computer $ComputerName not reachable (PING) - Skipping this computer..." }

#If computer does answer the ping
Else { Write-Output "Computer $computerName is online"

#Search into Users
$LocalUsers = "Users"
$Group = [ADSI]("WinNT://$computerName/$localUsers,group")
$Group.Members() |
foreach {
$AdsPath = $_.GetType().InvokeMember('Adspath', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
$A = $AdsPath.split('/',[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
$Names = $a[-1] 
$Domain = $a[-2]

#Gets the list of users to be removed from a TXT that you specify and checks if theres a match in the local group
foreach ($name in $names) {
Write-Output "Verifying the local users on computer $computerName" 
$localuser = Get-Content "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\User Deletion Scripts\TestUsers.txt"
foreach ($localuser in $localuser) {
if ($name -eq $localuser) {

#If it finds a match it will notify you and then remove the user from the local users group
Write-Output "User $localuser found on computer $computerName ... "
Remove-LocalUser $localuser

Write-Output "Removed" }}}}}

#Passes all the information of the operations made into the log file
}Stop-Transcript
```

When I test it, the VM gets the ping. However I get this:

```
The following exception occurred while retrieving member "Members": "The 
network path was not found.
"
At C:\Users\admin\Downloads\User Deletion Scripts\Remove-LocalAdmins 
Masive.ps1:39 char:1
+ $Group.Members() |
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemExceptio 
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember
```

Maybe I am missing something regarding firewalls or something, but I need a way for this script to work from my computer to the VM. What do I need to modify in the script to accomplish the deletion of users?

According to the comments below, my script should look something like this?

```
    $Computer = Get-Content "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Delete-Users\Computer(s).txt"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName.Trim() -ScriptBlock {

#enable remoting
Enable-PSRemoting -Force

#Get local users from admin group
$LocalUsers = "Users"
$Group = [ADSI]("WinNT://$computerName/$localUsers,group")
$Group.Members() |
foreach {
$AdsPath = $_.GetType().InvokeMember('Adspath', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
$A = $AdsPath.split('/',[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
$Names = $a[-1] 
$Domain = $a[-2]

$LocalUser = foreach ($name in $names) {
Write-Output "Verifying the local users on computer $computerName" 
$localuser = Get-Content "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Delete-Users\User(s).txt"
foreach ($localuser in $localuser) {
if ($name -eq $localuser) {

Foreach($User in $LocalUser){
#Check if the user is the one to delete and delete it using Remove-LocalUser
Write-Output "User $localuser found on computer $computerName ... "
Remove-LocalUser $localuser
Write-Output "Removed" 

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you text file doesn't contain any trailing spaces.

And I would like to point out some mistakes in the code.

- `foreach ($localuser in $localuser)` doesn't work, I believe its a typo and you can understand this.
- `Remove-LocalUser $localuser` won't work as the `$LocalUser` is a user from th VM and `Remove-LocalUser` is executed in the local machine.

You can do everything inside an `Invoke-Command` like below.

```
$Computer = Get-Content "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\User Deletion Scripts\TestLocal.txt"
Invoke-Command -CompuerName $ComputerName.Trim() -ScriptBlock {
    #Get local users from admin group
    $LocalUser = #Get all the local users
    Foreach($User in $LocalUser){
       #Check if the user is the one to delete and delete it using Remove-LocalUser
   }

}
```

If your VMs are in hyper-V, then you can use PowerShell direct which is not depended on any Network connection.

See more [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2015/05/14/powershell-direct-running-powershell-inside-a-virtual-machine-from-the-hyper-v-host/) about PowerShell direct.

Comment: so essentially this would replace the middle part of the script?

Comment: This replaces whole script, you have to fill the commented area with appropriate code.

Comment: Provided connectivity, `psexec` works for VMs in any HyperVisor

Comment: How do I use the Trim string? I am not very familiar with it.

Comment: I changed my script to how you suggested. I have it above in my question now. Is that how it should look like?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what version of PowerShell you are running?

v5 has cmdlets for local user management, and if you are not there, there is a model on the MS PS Gallery for local user management.

You are trying to hit remote host, and you don't say how you have PSRemting setup. Meaning, if this is a domain that your workstation and hosts are in or if it is a workgroup.

You are trying to use local variables on a remote host, and you are not setting the variable scope for that to work.

- PSRemoting must be enabled for this to work.
- You must scope your variables to be used remotely.
- You will need to use Invoke-Command to run this code on the remote
  host.
- You must be an admin on each remote host.

So, this middle part should be changed to something like this...

```
Else 
{ 
    Write-Output "Computer $computerName is online"

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -ScriptBlock {
        # Search into Users
        $LocalUsers = "Users"
        $Group = [ADSI]("WinNT://$Using:computerName/$localUsers,group")

        $Group.Members() |
        foreach 
        {
            $AdsPath = $_.GetType().InvokeMember('Adspath', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
            $A = $AdsPath.split('/',[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
            $Names = $a[-1] 
            $Domain = $a[-2]


            # Gets the list of users to be removed from a TXT that you specify and 
            # checks if theres a match in the local group

            foreach ($name in $names) 
            {
                Write-Output "Verifying the local users on computer $computerName" 
                $localuser = Get-Content "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\User Deletion Scripts\TestUsers.txt"

                foreach ($localuser in $localuser) 
                {
                    if ($name -eq $localuser) 
                    {

                        # If it finds a match it will notify you and then remove 
                        # the user from the local users group

                        Write-Output "User $localuser found on computer $computerName ... "
                        Remove-LocalUser $localuser

                        Write-Output "Removed" 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well I am running Power Shell version 5 but if it is possible I would like to be able to run it on version 4 and 3 since I plan to use this across a couple servers in the future.

Comment: By the way, I tried your script and I got this:  'Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM 
client cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the 
following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit 
credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.

Comment: I am using PSexec to execute the script remotely. Would that still work?